# Shopping Cart/Login State - No Cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, html, session, cookies

No cookies at all. Is that possible? And how exactly?

The only thing I can think of is if you create a hidden button with an id when the user first accesses the site. That id can then be propagated from page to page. When something is added to a shopping cart, you use ajax to save that selection to the id.

Comment: sessions don't have to use cookies, its just how they usually are done, otherwise a session id can be propagated through the url

Comment: perhaps telling us why you have a good reason to not use cookies, in this case would help with suggestions

Comment: And session propagation via URLs can lead to super-easy [session fixation vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).  Where is the no-cookie requirement coming from?  PHP session best practices actually dictate *requiring* cookie-based sessions, to prevent common fixation attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Ye olde method was indeed propagating the token as a GET or POST variable  throughout the process, which easily breaks (hence still the possibility in the session settings to enable it automatically with [url_rewriter.tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.url-rewriter.tags) ).

It can so easily break however, I don't think there's anything wrong with requiring people to enable cookies if they *want* to buy something from your site...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be a hidden field, a URL parameter con serve. You keep an id generator and that id is passed as a parameter ?i=xxxxx on every URL. You then store stuff in the card associated to the id.

Answer (score 0):

Session. They are no cookies. Notice they are named different...

I implemented this one in a breeze for a last project
https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Answer (score -1):

Sessions can track user until browser closed.

Comment: @Miquel  they don't have to be. see above

Comment: I know, look at my answer, but I got the impression that SIFE thinks sessions are automagical

Comment: they are *magical*, php will propagate the session id via the url with out you having to do anything

Comment: @Miquel I suggest you to read carefully how session works in PHP, and what is session hijacking?